# In this song, who is the fondue talking to?

Tags: questions

I'm not good in English, so this can be awkward – I'm sorry.

> "I've been searching my whole life to find my own place / and maybe it is the party talking or the chocolate fondue / but with you I found myself"

This passage is coming from one of the film Frozen's OST called 'Love Is an Open Door'.

What I want to ask you is whether "and maybe it is the party talking or the chocolate fondue" is linked with former sentence or latter sentence

If it is linked with former sentence, it might be meaning: *I said, "I've been searching my whole life to find my own place" – which I didn't say in a normal mood because I'm so happy right now*.

If it is linked with latter sentence, it might be meaning: *I'm so happy right now so I have to say "I found my place."*

Comment: General advice: Please avoid titles like "can I ask something about English". Every post on this site is asking something about English. I suggest you try to make a more specific title.

Comment: Sorry, i never used this site before... actually this is my first post in foreigner site

Comment: I must say, this is an impressive first question. A lot of new users get pointed [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) for some helpful advice, but you seem to have the hang of it already. Secondly, there won't be any need to apologize for unpolished English here – you are the kind of person this site was designed to help. Thanks for making it a better place!

Answer (score 7):

The idiom "maybe it's the [substance] talking" means the speaker is under the influence of a chemical substance and is saying things s/he would not normally say due to the intoxicated state. So in fact it's the speaker talking, not the fondue (but it is the fondue that is making him/her say it.)

For example: **"Maybe it's the beer talking, Marge. But you've got a butt that won't quit."**
 *([The Simpsons](http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/hey-mom-did-you-save-dads-love-letters-of-course-i-saved-t/))*

In the case of Frozen, the writers are slipping some humor for adults into a kids film by making the intoxicating substance into an innocuous *chocolate fondue*.

So a good interpretation of the lyric might be, "Because the party atmosphere and chocolate I have consumed have loosened my inhibitions, I am telling you that I gained self-knowledge in the time spent with you."

Comment: Note also that alcohol could well be present in a fondue (wine or sherry in a cheese fondue, or rum or brandy in a chocolate one). So the intoxicating substance in the fondue isn't necessarily merely chocolate!

Answer (score 5):

I can understand your question.  :)  Let's break the sentence apart, and explain the idiomatic "maybe it's the party talking".

> I've been searching my whole life to find my place.  Maybe I'm not in my usual state of mind (and maybe I am), but (the way I feel right now is that) with you I (have) found myself.

The two latter sentences are more strongly bound together than the first one is, because the first of them (maybe I'm not in my usual state of mind) weakens the statement in the second one.  However, the speaker is seeing all three sentences are part of a single idea.  That's why the first sentence is bound together with "and".  There's a sense of trying to get all of that idea out at once, so the listener can evaluate it all in one piece.

So, the short answer to your question is that they are all linked together.

Comment: +1 But OP may need some explanation how "it's the party talking or the chocolate fondue" is equivalent to "I'm not in my usual state of mind"; it's not a real obvious idiom.

Comment: To Stoney. actually I knew about that. but thank you

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I should have "spelled that out."  Thank you!

Comment: +1 I upvoted both the question and the answer. But the part *"But with you I found myself"* threw me off (I found myself *what*?), so I searched the web and found the lyrics. That part should be *"But with you I found my place."* Not something very serious, but just in case that it might confuse someone else like it did to me. :-)

Comment: @Damkerng T: To "find oneself" means to come to an understanding of one's meaning or purpose in life. See [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/find+oneself).  (In this case, the reflexive pronoun functions as the direct object in the sentence.) Also the term "lyrics" exclusively refers to words of a poem or song. It's related to the word "lyre"; see [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lyric).

Comment: @BobRodes Thank you for the "find oneself". Maybe the first part *"I've been searching my whole life to find my place,"* made me expect that she must have been finding her place her whole life, so I was surprised by that *"find myself"*. Btw, isn't it a part of lyrics (of a song) we're talking about in here? :P

Comment: Why, so it is.  I thought it was some sort of movie dialog.  Sorry!  I've just educated myself on what an "OST" is.  I should have recognized that something that "cheesy" would have to be in a song.  :)

Comment: Oh my god. I wrote it wrong.. It isn't "I find myself." Actually, It is "I find my place". What a shame. I just wrote it just my ears said. Sorry...